# My Image function doesn't work, how do I fix this?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am following the android developers codelab. It says after I include the import the error will be solved but it hasn't.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun GreetingImage(message: String, from: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier){
    val image = painterResource(R.drawable.androidparty)
    Image(
        painter = image
    )

}
```

The error I get;

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
Image(ImageBitmap, String?, Modifier = ..., Alignment = ..., ContentScale = ..., Float = ..., ColorFilter? = ..., FilterQuality = ...) defined in androidx.compose.foundation
Image(Painter, String?, Modifier = ..., Alignment = ..., ContentScale = ..., Float = ..., ColorFilter? = ...) defined in androidx.compose.foundation
Image(ImageVector, String?, Modifier = ..., Alignment = ..., ContentScale = ..., Float = ..., ColorFilter? = ...) defined in androidx.compose.foundation

I imported the class "import androidx.compose.foundation.Image" but it still gives me the same error.
I know this is a basic problem but I am new to coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must provide content description parameter to an image in compose. In your case it will be

```
@Composable
fun GreetingImage(message: String, from: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier){
    val image = painterResource(R.drawable.androidparty)
    Image(
        painter = image,
        contentDescription = null // Here you can provide content description if you want
    )
}
```